# TypeError: the range object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to implement a simple python function to generate a list of all prime numbers up to a given  . you can find the code snippet below.

```
def prime_list(n):
  non = []
  for i in range(2, n+1):
    for j in range(2, n+1):
      if i*j<=n:
        non.append(i*j)
  non.append(1)
  unique = set(non)
  prime = []
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i not in unique:
      prime.append(i)

  prime = list(prime)
  return prime    

my_prime = prime_list(100)
print(my_prime)
```

After, I run the program, I got this error:

**TypeError: the range object is not callable**

I checked if I have defined the list as a variable anywhere, but I have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the error like you overwrote the `range` builtin by naming a variable "range"?

Generally to remove a variable from memory, you don't have to restart the notebook kernel, you can use the `del` keyword/builtin.

e.g.

```py
example = [1,2]

del example

print(example)

# NameError: name 'example' is not defined
```

Even deleting variables shadowing names of builtins works, and replaces the reference to the builtin.

e.g.

```py
range = [1, 2, 3]       # oops!

del range

for i in range(10):
    print(i)

# 1
# 2
# 3 etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to restart the kernel and run everything.

Because if you once defined a variable called list, even if you deleted it afterwards, the notebook will treat "list" as a variable, until you restart the kernel.

**Restarting the kernel solves my issues!**